# What is a degenerate parabolic partial equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have came across the following pde:
$u_t-\left(\int_{\Omega}u^2(x,t)dx\right)^{\gamma}\Delta u=f(x,t),\quad (x,t)\in \Omega\times(0,T]$. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded open domain in $\mathbb{R}^d,d=1,2,3$ and $\gamma$ is a real constant. If $\gamma=0$ we have the heat equation. For $\gamma>0$ the problem could degenerate if there is an extinction phenomenon, and for $\gamma<0$ if the extinction occurs the problem becomes singular. Now I an not understanding the exact meaning of degenerate here. Also is this equation is degenerate only for $\gamma>0$ or it can be degenerate for $\gamma<0$ too? What is the difference between problem could degenerate and problem to be singular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a PDE of the form
$$
u_t - Tr(A(x, t) D^2 u) + b(x, t) \cdot \nabla u + c(x, t) u = f(x, t),
$$
one typically says it is parabolic if $A(x, t)$ is positive (semi)definite, i.e. at every $x, t$ you have $\xi \cdot A(x, t)\xi \geq 0$ for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This is all great, but a "parabolic" equation of this type can have some obvious problems, like for example if $A = 0$. In this case it still has some familiar aspects (a maximum principle) but not others (regularization of any sort); no one working on this thinks of it as parabolic. Usually you want to use the word parabolic to make an analogy to the heat equation, and here the analogy is poor.

Let's say that $\lambda(x, t)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A(x, t)$, and $\Lambda(x, t)$ is the largest. A definition commonly encountered in the literature is *uniformly parabolic*, meaning $0 < \lambda < \lambda(x, t) \leq \Lambda(x, t) < \Lambda < \infty$ on the domain in question. If you assume this, the analogy with the heat equation becomes very good: the PDE is regularizing, it has infinite speed of propagation, etc.

It's reasonable, however, to ask whether this assumption is necessary. There are many ways to relax it, to accommodate some popular PDE. But before we do this, there's a nontrivial observation that has been made over years of research on this topic: if the ratio $\Lambda(x, t)/\lambda(x, t)$ is unbounded, the PDE typically loses most of its "heat equation like" characteristics. Maybe if $\Lambda(x, t)/\lambda(x, t)$ blows up extremely slowly (think logs or iterated logs) you can say something, and there is a substantial literature on this topic, but there are also just counterexamples to most regularity theorems you can think of. So unless your equation has some very special structure you can exploit, you will likely want to stick to situations where this ratio is bounded.

That simplifies our life somewhat, because near a given point, if $\Lambda(x, t)/\lambda(x, t)$ is bounded but the PDE is not uniformly parabolic, either $\lambda(x, t), \Lambda(x, t) \rightarrow 0$ or they tend to $\infty$. The former case is called *degenerate*, the latter case *singular*. They at least seem to be qualitatively different: heuristically, a degenerate PDE has very slow speed of propagation, while a singular PDE has a very fast one. It turns out there are usually changes of variable that can map one to the other (by rescaling one of the independent variables, for example), but they also change any nonlinear structure your equation may have had. So in the literature they will sometimes be considered together as kind of dual situations, but for a given equation they will have distinct meanings.

Now, you may note that you have some nonlinear PDE which is not the linear one I wrote down. Nonlinear PDE like that can be rewritten as linear PDE ($A = (\int u^2)^\gamma I$ in this case), which at least lets you check which situation you are in. Here, if $\int u^2 \rightarrow 0$, you are in trouble for uniform parabolicity: you will have a degenerate or singular equation depending on the sign of $\gamma$. You also have a lot of extra structure to help you analyze the equation, which is typical in this subject: the theory of general degenerate or singular PDE is very limited, and also very difficult to apply to a given nonlinear PDE a priori.

In particular, the suggestion I made above that one should assume $\Lambda(x, t)/\lambda(x, t) \leq C$ is often (usually?) impossible to check directly in practice for a given nonlinear PDE. So the terms degenerate/singular will either be used in a non-rigorous sense (so, for your equation, when $\gamma > 0$ I will call it degenerate, because if $\int u^2 \rightarrow 0$ at some $t$ it *is* degenerate in my sense--but I have not shown that $t \mapsto \int u^2$ is continuous or bounded or anything, which would be needed to make this rigorous), or sometimes in some weaker sense (for example, saying the equation is degenerate if you have the one-sided bound $0 \leq \lambda(x, t) \leq \Lambda(x, t) < \Lambda < \infty$).